# Error finding location when using CoreLocation

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, core-location

I'm trying to grab a user's location using XCode 7.1 & for iOS 9.1.

I don't see any errors in the code, but I keep getting this same error every time I try getting the location. `Error finding location: The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)`

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import CoreLocation

class secondview: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var player = AVPlayer() // Audio Player
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager() // Location Manager


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //PlayEntryAudio() // Start playing entry audio
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
        locationManager.requestLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if let location = locations.first {
            print("Current location: \(location)")
        } else {
            // ...
        }
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
        print("Error finding location: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }



    func PlayEntryAudio(){
        print("Got here")
        let url = NSURL(string: "https://9147abb4.ngrok.io/track.mp4")!
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem( URL:url)
        player = AVPlayer(playerItem:playerItem)
        player.play()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Edit 01: Noticed that I wasn't getting an alert asking me to get location, so I tried adding `locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` to no success.

Comment: You need to request permission via `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` and include a reason string in your info.plist

Comment: Yep, that was it. You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @Paulw11 I'm getting a location back like this: Current location: <+15.70204910,+239.17552610> +/- 5.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 10/24/15, 12:54:38 PM Pacific Daylight Time, the timezone is correct, but the actual location is way off. Are those coordinates (Lat, Long)?

Comment: Those numbers don't look right to mel. In particular the east/west value should be less than 180

Comment: I directly changed some of those numbers before I made that comment (I don't want to accidentally show me location on the web).

Comment: Oh, ok.  Then yes, those numbers are Lat and Lon. Your determined location will depend on the environment you are in and the device. If you are indoors without a good GPS signal then wifi triangulation is used which may not be accurate but it shows +/- 5m so accuracy seems good. Was this test on the simulator or a real device?

Comment: This was done on my physical iPhone running iOS 9.1, connected to a WiFi network.

Comment: Got it, it seems like it works when I switch back to a cellular connection. But why would a Wi-Fi network be showing a location in China?

Comment: The NSA? Don't know :) but with wifi only and no GPS it is basically looking up the network name in a database. If your wifi name isn't there but there is an entry for another network with the same name you can get mis located